# Spacing list values

Tags: python, list

Let me apologize up front for the vague title here--I really tried to come up with something better. I am working on a program which generates lists of about 250 elements, each element being 1, 0, or -1. What I am trying to do eliminate nearby occurrences of 1s. 
Let say my buffer is 3. Anywhere in the list that a 1 occurs I want to be sure that no other 1 occurs in the next 3 positions and if there is one in one of those 3 positions I want to replace it with a 0.  So [1,0,0,1,0,0] becomes [1,0,0,0,0,0]. Also [1,0,1,0,1] becomes [1,0,0,0,1] since by the time the last 1 is processed the one that was in position 3 has already been changed to 0. Also, I'd like the buffer width to be a parameter which can change from run to run.
I've tried to do this with a list comprehension, including using enumerate, but I have not managed to get anything to work.
Thanks

Comment: What about nearby occurences of `-1`? Do you treat is as `1`? So after `1` or `-1` there's at least 3 zeros?

Comment: The -1s don't cause a problem. A -1 can occur immediately after a 1. That's ok

Comment: Do you have a **specific** technical issue with your code?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you only want values == `1` spaced from other `1` at least `n` places:

```
from random import choice
from itertools import islice

def generate(n=250, b=3):
    def _g():
        while True:
            v = choice([-1, 0, 1])
            yield v
            if v == 1:
                yield from (choice([0, -1]) for i in range(b))
    yield from islice(_g(), 0, n)

out = list(generate(250, 3))
print(out)
```

Prints (for example):

```
[0, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, -1, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, -1, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 0, -1, 1, -1, 0, 0, 1, -1, -1, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, -1, -1, -1, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, -1, 1, -1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, -1, 0, -1, 1, 0, -1, -1, 1, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 1, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1, 0, -1, 0, 1, -1, -1, 0, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, -1, 1, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 1, 0, -1, -1, 0, 0]
```

---

EDIT: For filtering list, you can use this example:

```
from random import choice
from itertools import islice

def my_filter(lst, b=3):
    i = iter(lst)

    while True:
        try:
            v = next(i)
            yield v
            if v == 1:
                yield from (0 if v==1 else v for v in islice(i, 0, b))
        except StopIteration:
            break

lst = [choice([1, 0, -1]) for i in range(250)]

print('Original list:')
print(lst)

print('Filtered list:')
print(list(my_filter(lst, 3)))
```

Prints (for example):

```
Original list:
[-1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 0, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, -1, 0, -1, 0, 1, -1, 0, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 0, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 0, -1, -1, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 1, -1, -1, -1, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, -1, -1, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, -1, -1, 0, 1, -1, 0, 1, 0, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 0, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 0, 0, -1, -1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, -1, -1, 1, 0, 1]
Filtered list:
[-1, 1, -1, 0, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0, -1, 1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0, -1, 0, 1, -1, 0, -1, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 0, -1, -1, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1, 0, 1, -1, -1, -1, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, -1, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, -1, -1, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 0, -1, 1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, -1, -1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, -1, -1, 1, 0, 0]
```

Comment: But I have not control over the input list which may contain 1s in close proximity to each other. That I want to do is clean up the list, so that there is a minimum gap between 1s and I want to do that by replacing the following nearby 1s with 0s

Comment: Close. But in the original list the entries in the 9th and 10th positions are both 1 and in the filtered list they are 0,1; should be 1,0. Same with positions 13 & 14. 18&19 are handled correctly.

Comment: @dborger But if the values in filtered list at 9th&10th position is `1, 0` instead of `0, 1`, the space between previous `1` and next `1` is 2, not 3 - `[-1, 1, -1, 0, -1, -1, 1, **-1**, **-1**, 1, 0, ...`

Comment: My bad. I missed the 1 at position  which requires position 9 to be 0 and makes 10 ok as 1. I need to try this on some of my actual cases as well as read through the code carefully to understand how it works. Thanks a lot.